# Log message as express app.listen callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am introducing winston logging into my application and i would like to replace all info or error level logs with winston's `.info` and `.error`. So far everything works except when I try and log a info message from within app.listen callback.

`appStartup.js` file where logger is defined

```
const app = require('express')();
const co = require('co');
const cors = require('cors');
const winston = require('winston');

const loggerTimeFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();

const winstonLogger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      timestamp: loggerTimeFormat,
    }),
  ],
});

module.exports = function appStartup() {
  co(function* services() {
    app.db = mongo.connect();
    app.use(cors());
    app.set('logger', winstonLogger);
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });

  return app;
};
```

In my `server.js` file I have:

```
const app = require('./src/appStartup');

const appPort = process.env.PORT;
app().listen(appPort, () => {
  console.log('Info message here');
});
```

I would like to replace the `console.log` in `server.js` with a winston `info` log I tried doing this:

```
const app = require('./src/appStartup');
const appPort = process.env.PORT;
const appObj = app();

appObj.listen(appPort, (appObj.get('logger')) => {
  logger.info('Info message here');
});
```

Not sure if that's the right syntax though, I get `Parsing error: Assigned to rvalue` for `appObj` in `appObj.get('logger')`. Any idea how can I make this work?

Comment: logger invocation seems to have a typo. You don’t have logger.info, but only logger.

Comment: @Sri Yeah thank you that was a typo, though that didnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you mean this?

```
appObj.listen(appPort, (logger = appObj.get('logger')) => {
  logger.info('Info message here');
});
```

`logger` is the name of the argument, `appObj.get('logger')` is its default value.

Also, you're using `co()` when there's no need to use it, and its likely causing the problem because it's executing the code inside the `services` function at the next tick of the event loop (i.e. it's calling `app.set('logger', ...)` *after* calling `appObj.get('logger')`).

Try this:

```
module.exports = function appStartup() {
  app.use(cors());
  app.set('logger', winstonLogger);
  return app;
};
```

**EDIT**: if `appStartup` depends on something asynchronous, one solution would be to return a promise from it, and handle it "upstream":

```
module.exports = function appStartup() {
  app.use(cors());
  app.set('logger', winstonLogger);
  return mongo.connect().then(db => {
    app.db = db;
    return app;
  });
};

// server.js
const app = require('./src/appStartup');
const appPort = process.env.PORT;

app().then(appObj => {
  appObj.listen(appPort, (logger = appObj.get('logger')) => {
    logger.info('Info message here');
  });
}).catch(e => {
  console.error('Unable to create app', e);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Or using `async/await`, which works on recent (8.x) Node.js versions:

```
module.exports = async function appStartup() {
  app.use(cors());
  app.set('logger', winstonLogger);
  app.db = await mongo.connect();
  return app;
};

// server.js
const app     = require('./src/appStartup');
const appPort = process.env.PORT;

void async function() { // async IIFE
  try {
    var appObj = await app();
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('Unable to create app', e);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  appObj.listen(appPort, (logger = appObj.get('logger')) => {
    logger.info('Info message here');
  });
}();
```

Comment: ah that makes sense, it resolved the parsing error, but appObj.get('logger') is returning undefined, even though I did set it in the appStartup app.set('logger', winstonLogger);

Comment: @user988544 `appObj` seems to be a new instance.

Comment: It would still be a new instance of  `require('./src/appStartup');` right? so it should have the properties set in `appStartup.js` ? I am probably not understanding this correctly

Comment: @user988544 oh hang on, the issue is likely the use of `co()`. You don't need it.

Comment: What do you mean I dont need it? and how could it be the issue? Can you expand a little bit please

Comment: It's causing the issue because it's asynchronous, but the code inside it isn't (so it's not needed because of the latter, and it's causing the problem because the logger is set to the `app` instance "too late" because of the former). See edit.

Comment: Well my bad, I didnt copy the entire function, theres a call to mongodb and that is why I need it to be non-blocking if I re-write without using `co` it returns rejection in promise, `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: failed to connect to server`

Answer (score 0):

It is an known issue with `babel-eslint`. Try upgrading it to a latest version and it will resolve the issue.

[Check this thread for more info](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/190)

As a temporary solution you may try considering rewriting your arrow function in `es5` way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not sure if that's the issue, when I try babel validator online I am getting "Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters"